# Change alias / nickname / callsign for Steam friends

Tags: steam

Some of my friends on Steam change nicknames so often I can hardly remember who's who. Is there any way I can set custom nicknames for friends in Steam?

Best workaround I've got so far is using tags, but that's not what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since some time now, Steam has built in support for adding a nickname to a friend. Note that this doesn't *change* a nickname, but rather *adds* one to your friend's name in parentheses. It works like this:

**First**, right-click on your friend's name:
[image: right-click on the name of a friend]

**Second**, choose a nickname:
[image: enter a nick]

**Result** is a nickname behind your friend's current alias:
[image: resulting friends list]

Comment: The other party doesn't see what you've nicknamed them, correct?

Comment: @Camus AFAIK they don't. But you must have some interesting nick names for your friends if you worry about that :)

Answer (score 8):

Actually, yes, this is possible. Valve implemented this functionality as early as 2010. However, they never exposed this functionality in the client itself for some reason.

Luckily, however, someone created an app to do exactly this.

You can find the forum thread in which it was released [here](http://facepunch.com/threads/1043138), and a direct download link here:

[FriendManager_v0.5.rar](https://bitbucket.org/VoiDeD/open-steamworks/downloads/FriendManager_v0.5.rar)

Usage is very simple. You launch the application, set a new name, and close it again. Aliases should be bound to your account and therefore work forever, but they might be stored in the client. At any rate, you won't need to keep the application running to keep the aliases.

An example of this plugin in action:

[image]

The alias is in front, and the original name is appended in brackets.

Answer (score 3):

The [Steam Community Beta](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/NewSteamCommunityBeta) has added a context menu item to set nicknames for your friends in Steam's Friends interface, and the functionality has been made standard for the current Steam version. Click the down arrow next to your friend's name and hit "add nickname".

Comment: I was very afraid this would be the answer to my question :-(. Could not find many resources on it here or via Google though, so I'm hoping someone else has a clever solution...

Comment: Drop me a line if they do, I would be very interested too.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. ;-) (Placing a comment here so it'll ping @kotekzot)

Comment: @ArdaXi thanks for the answer and for letting me know!